# Native Code Capture Image throws exception on IOS 11?

Tags: ios, objective-c, codenameone, native, ios11

I have a problem with objective-c code that handles openning camera to take a picture the code is injected as native code inside codename one

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
            imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            imagePicker.delegate = self;


            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            NSArray *mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage, nil];
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = mediaTypes;
            imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
            [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
        }else{
            [self showAlert:@"No Camera Privilege On This Device"];
        }
```

the problem is when the above code is executed on iOS-11 ,I get null pointer exception from codenameone without asking for camera permission unlike iOS-12
the code works perfectly

the permission are added in the codenamesettings

```
codename1.arg.ios.NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription=The App uses the Photo Library to save Images downloaded from News
codename1.arg.ios.NSCameraUsageDescription=The App uses the Camera for Video Chat support
codename1.arg.ios.NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription=The App uses the Photo Library to save Images downloaded from News
```

is there anything that can be done to handle the issue on iOS11

--exception stack-trace from simulator using Xcode9.2

```
2018-10-04 18:47:50.830359+0300 TestApplication[7630:35311] *** Assertion failure in -[UIApplication _cachedSystemAnimationFenceCreatingIfNecessary:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3698.33.6/UIApplication.m:1709
2018-10-04 18:47:50.853277+0300 TestApplication[7630:35311] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'accessing _cachedSystemAnimationFence requires the main thread'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010da7312b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d107f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010da782f2 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000109d38d69 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000107ac692d -[UIApplication _cachedSystemAnimationFenceCreatingIfNecessary:] + 359
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000107b51ac9 +[UIWindow _synchronizeDrawingWithPreCommitHandler:] + 57
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001082cfb7b -[UIInputViewAnimationStyle launchAnimation:afterStarted:completion:forHost:fromCurrentPosition:] + 99
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010872be9a -[UIInputWindowController moveFromPlacement:toPlacement:starting:completion:] + 1697
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000108734c8f __43-[UIInputWindowController setInputViewSet:]_block_invoke.1493 + 97
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000108724208 -[UIInputWindowController performOperations:withTemplateNotificationInfo:] + 46
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010873481b -[UIInputWindowController setInputViewSet:] + 1336
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010872b450 -[UIInputWindowController performOperations:withAnimationStyle:] + 50
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001082c8164 -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) setInputViews:animationStyle:] + 1669
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001082bff4b -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _reloadInputViewsForResponder:] + 2163
    14  UIKit                               0x00000001082c9480 -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _preserveInputViewsWithId:animated:reset:] + 498
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000107c89130 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:modalSourceViewController:presentationController:animationController:interactionController:completion:] + 1233
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000107c8ae94 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 4621
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000107c8d9a9 __63-[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 99
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000107c8e079 -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 532
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000107c8d908 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 181
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000107c8dc67 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 159
```

appreciate the help

Regards,

Comment: Please add an exception breakpoint in Xcode, then post the code around the failing line.  The issue (which is buried in the hard to crash output) is that some place (probably after the picker is done) your app is attempting to update the UI off the main thread.  This is easily fixable once we know where the problem is.

Comment: @danh it doesn't reach the image picker , based on the watched variables , imagePicker = nil , that means we didn't reach the line where the allocation occurs

Comment: The reason I gave a guess rather than an answer is that I'm not sure you've posted the most pertinent source.  The way to do that is by setting an exception breakpoint and posting the context around the line that triggers the crash

Comment: @danh , what is your input that the same code works on iOS12 ?? , one might think maybe there are some snippet of code that iOS11 is not compatible with maybe handling transition or presenting the image picker view controller ???

Comment: I guess there are two methods to investigate this: (1) enumerate all of the changes between OS releases, and for each change wonder, did this cause my crash?, (2) look at the location of the crash in the code, debug and fix.  Let me know if you want help with method 2, I'll be happy to help.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the source code of Codename One and how we dealt with these things in our capture implementation https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Ports/iOSPort/nativeSources/IOSNative.m it uses the same API's you did if I remember correctly

Comment: @Shai , I saw that you do this : `[[CodenameOne_GLViewController instance] presentModalViewController:pickerController animated:YES];` , but it is the same thing except for Modal , is that a reason to cause exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all of your help , the problem as stated was only on iOS11 , and the reason for that if I present any viewcontroller with animated:Yes and I changed how to call the view controller by adding the following code

```
dispatch_queue_t _serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("x.y.z", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
dispatch_sync(_serialQueue, ^{
        self.filePath=param;
        [self showForm];

    });
```

and the showForm : just take a copy of the old viewcontroller and present the new one like this [condition was used to wait for the camera to finish picking and saving the file to gallery] :

```
-(void)showForm{
    condition = [[NSCondition alloc] init];
    self.parentViewController = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
    [self.parentViewController.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    destinationViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithValues:self.filePath andCondition:condition andChoice:@"Camera"];
    [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] presentViewController:destinationViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    [condition lock];
    [condition wait];    
    self.filePath = [(ViewController*)destinationViewController getImagePath];
    [self.parentViewController.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [condition unlock];



}
```

I hope that would help any one who needs it

Regards,

Comment: the above worked but cause the application animation of the page before navigation to freeze for a bit